# TypeError: done is not a function (node.js, express, but not passport)

Tags: node.js, express

What am I doing wrong? Something obvious is happening but can't realise what.

> **TypeError:** done is not a function (node.js express) at
>   profile-update.js, line 24.

profile-update.js

```
        var User= require("../models/user.js");

        var profileUpdate= function(req, res, done){

        User.findOne({"basic.usernameID": req.body.basicUsernameID}, function(err, user){

            if(err){

                return done(err)

            }

            user.profile.email= req.body.emailInput;

            user.save(function(err){

                if(err){

                    return done(err)

                }

                return done(null, user) /*this line seems to cause trouble*/

            });

        });

    }

    exports.profileUpdate=profileUpdate;
```

index.js

```
 router.post("/user-update", function(req, res){

 userUpdate.profileUpdate(req, res);

});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You are only passing two arguments to `profileUpdate`: `userUpdate.profileUpdate(req, res);`. You are not passing a value for `done`, the third parameter. Did you expect the third argument to magically exist? Or why are you only passing two arguments?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164837/difference-between-done-and-next-in-node-js-callbacks)?

Comment: right! tnx @FelixKling