# Even after entering wrong credentials Passport.js login function is not creating any err and making the user authenticated

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Hi I am using nodeJs Passport npm package

I am trying to use login functionality, the code I am using is this:

```
let User = new mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

// use static authenticate method of model in LocalStrategy
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

// use static serialize and deserialize of model for passport session support
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.post("/login", function(req, res){
   const user =  new User({
       username: req.body.username,
       password: req.body.password
   });

   req.login(user, function(err){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           res.redirect("/login");
       }else{
           // all cookies are saved, sessions working now
           passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            res.redirect("/secrets");
        });
       }
   });
});
```

But when I enters wrong password, it says **UnAuthorized** but it is also going to authenticate function and making the user authenticated.

May I know what is the issue in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
(Fix me if I'm wrong, but it seems very like a code from Angela Yu's course:) )

I noticed that in [Passport.js docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) its always using the `passport.authenticate` method but not the `req.login()`.
[Docs says that](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/)

> Passport exposes a `login()` function on `req` (also aliased as `logIn()`)
> that can be used to establish a login session.

And that the `login()` function is used inside the `passport.authenticate` to create session.

So I think whats going on is the code:

1. You enter wrong password on login page
2. `req.login()` creates a session cookies as if that was true user, i.e. it **logs you in** (since err object in login()'s callback is not for authentication errors, but for some other purposes)
3. then , since `err` object in `login()` callback is not for authentication errors and stays `undefined` , `passport.authenticate(...)` is called and it gives you 401 error "Unauthorized" because the password was wrong..

But the cookie for you is already has been created by the `login()`. So you can access all the secret stuff after that.

so the code that works for me was just:

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/secrets");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is actually from Dr. Angela's code. This is what I used to fix it:

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
      passport.authenticate("local", {
          failureRedirect: "/loginfail"
        }
        (req, res, function() {
          res.redirect("/secrets")
        })
      })
```

`failureRedirect` is an option of `passport.authenticate`. You can place the custom message codes you want to display if the login fails in that route.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same issue.
The below code worked for me.
Took help from this post: [difference between 'done' and 'next' in node.js callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164837/difference-between-done-and-next-in-node-js-callbacks)

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res){

    const user= new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    })
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {

        if(err) { res.redirect('/login'); }
        if(user){
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) { res.redirect('/login'); }
                else res.redirect('/secrets');
            });
        }
        else{ 
            //Incorrect credentials, hence redirect to login 
            return res.redirect('/login'); 
        }
        
    })(req, res);
});
```